# How do I type this callback function using typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

In the code below I typed the dispatch function as "any". I am doing this to clear the error I get if I don't type it.

What is the correct way to type it with Typescript ?

```
export function doThing() {
  console.log("works")
  return (dispatch:any) => {  // any ?       
    fetch('https://whatever.com/some-api').then((response) => {
      return response.json()
    }).then((data) => {

      dispatch(pingApiAction(data))
    })
  };
}
```

Comment: what does `pingApiAction` return?

Comment: An Object literal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: How to type the Dispatch in Redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54844839/typescript-how-to-type-the-dispatch-in-redux)

Answer (score 0):

You should specify an interface for the return from `pingActionResult` and then use that in the definition of `dispatch`

Given, for example:

```
interface PingActionResult
{
    field1: string;
    field2: string;
}
```

Your code might look like:

```
export function doThing() {
  console.log("works")
  return (dispatch:(result:PingActionResult) => void) => {  // any ?       
    fetch('https://whatever.com/some-api').then((response) => {
      return response.json()
    }).then((data) => {

      dispatch(pingApiAction(data))
    })
  };
}

// just for illustration
function pingApiAction(data:{}): PingActionResult{
    return {field1: "foo", field2: "bar"}
}
```